# How can I resolve an 'Authentication Error' that occurs during the email signup process when using the Clerk authentication system?

Tags: authentication, next.js, clerk

I have an app that uses clerk authentication for sign ups, for some reason signing up works with all the sign in providers that clerk and when using these sign in providers the user  can successfully create a companion. When using Email sign up, the users who sign up under email gets an authentication error when trying to create a companion..

I get this error in browser console:

[image]

This is the **code that is causing the error** from browser console:

```
'use strict';

import utils from './../utils.js';
import settle from './../core/settle.js';
import cookies from './../helpers/cookies.js';
import buildURL from './../helpers/buildURL.js';
import buildFullPath from '../core/buildFullPath.js';
import isURLSameOrigin from './../helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js';
import transitionalDefaults from '../defaults/transitional.js';
import AxiosError from '../core/AxiosError.js';
import CanceledError from '../cancel/CanceledError.js';
import parseProtocol from '../helpers/parseProtocol.js';
import platform from '../platform/index.js';
import AxiosHeaders from '../core/AxiosHeaders.js';
import speedometer from '../helpers/speedometer.js';

function progressEventReducer(listener, isDownloadStream) {
  let bytesNotified = 0;
  const _speedometer = speedometer(50, 250);

  return e => {
    const loaded = e.loaded;
    const total = e.lengthComputable ? e.total : undefined;
    const progressBytes = loaded - bytesNotified;
    const rate = _speedometer(progressBytes);
    const inRange = loaded <= total;

    bytesNotified = loaded;

    const data = {
      loaded,
      total,
      progress: total ? (loaded / total) : undefined,
      bytes: progressBytes,
      rate: rate ? rate : undefined,
      estimated: rate && total && inRange ? (total - loaded) / rate : undefined,
      event: e
    };

    data[isDownloadStream ? 'download' : 'upload'] = true;

    listener(data);
  };
}

const isXHRAdapterSupported = typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined';

export default isXHRAdapterSupported && function (config) {
  return new Promise(function dispatchXhrRequest(resolve, reject) {
    let requestData = config.data;
    const requestHeaders = AxiosHeaders.from(config.headers).normalize();
    const responseType = config.responseType;
    let onCanceled;
    function done() {
      if (config.cancelToken) {
        config.cancelToken.unsubscribe(onCanceled);
      }

      if (config.signal) {
        config.signal.removeEventListener('abort', onCanceled);
      }
    }

    if (utils.isFormData(requestData)) {
      if (platform.isStandardBrowserEnv || platform.isStandardBrowserWebWorkerEnv) {
        requestHeaders.setContentType(false); // Let the browser set it
      } else {
        requestHeaders.setContentType('multipart/form-data;', false); // mobile/desktop app frameworks
      }
    }

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // HTTP basic authentication
    if (config.auth) {
      const username = config.auth.username || '';
      const password = config.auth.password ? unescape(encodeURIComponent(config.auth.password)) : '';
      requestHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
    }

    const fullPath = buildFullPath(config.baseURL, config.url);

    request.open(config.method.toUpperCase(), buildURL(fullPath, config.params, config.paramsSerializer), true);

    // Set the request timeout in MS
    request.timeout = config.timeout;

    function onloadend() {
      if (!request) {
        return;
      }
      // Prepare the response
      const responseHeaders = AxiosHeaders.from(
        'getAllResponseHeaders' in request && request.getAllResponseHeaders()
      );
      const responseData = !responseType || responseType === 'text' || responseType === 'json' ?
        request.responseText : request.response;
      const response = {
        data: responseData,
        status: request.status,
        statusText: request.statusText,
        headers: responseHeaders,
        config,
        request
      };

      settle(function _resolve(value) {
        resolve(value);
        done();
      }, function _reject(err) {
        reject(err);
        done();
      }, response);

      // Clean up request
      request = null;
    }

    if ('onloadend' in request) {
      // Use onloadend if available
      request.onloadend = onloadend;
    } else {
      // Listen for ready state to emulate onloadend
      request.onreadystatechange = function handleLoad() {
        if (!request || request.readyState !== 4) {
          return;
        }

        // The request errored out and we didn't get a response, this will be
        // handled by onerror instead
        // With one exception: request that using file: protocol, most browsers
        // will return status as 0 even though it's a successful request
        if (request.status === 0 && !(request.responseURL && request.responseURL.indexOf('file:') === 0)) {
          return;
        }
        // readystate handler is calling before onerror or ontimeout handlers,
        // so we should call onloadend on the next 'tick'
        setTimeout(onloadend);
      };
    }

    // Handle browser request cancellation (as opposed to a manual cancellation)
    request.onabort = function handleAbort() {
      if (!request) {
        return;
      }

      reject(new AxiosError('Request aborted', AxiosError.ECONNABORTED, config, request));

      // Clean up request
      request = null;
    };

    // Handle low level network errors
    request.onerror = function handleError() {
      // Real errors are hidden from us by the browser
      // onerror should only fire if it's a network error
      reject(new AxiosError('Network Error', AxiosError.ERR_NETWORK, config, request));

      // Clean up request
      request = null;
    };

    // Handle timeout
    request.ontimeout = function handleTimeout() {
      let timeoutErrorMessage = config.timeout ? 'timeout of ' + config.timeout + 'ms exceeded' : 'timeout exceeded';
      const transitional = config.transitional || transitionalDefaults;
      if (config.timeoutErrorMessage) {
        timeoutErrorMessage = config.timeoutErrorMessage;
      }
      reject(new AxiosError(
        timeoutErrorMessage,
        transitional.clarifyTimeoutError ? AxiosError.ETIMEDOUT : AxiosError.ECONNABORTED,
        config,
        request));

      // Clean up request
      request = null;
    };

    // Add xsrf header
    // This is only done if running in a standard browser environment.
    // Specifically not if we're in a web worker, or react-native.
    if (platform.isStandardBrowserEnv) {
      // Add xsrf header
      const xsrfValue = (config.withCredentials || isURLSameOrigin(fullPath))
        && config.xsrfCookieName && cookies.read(config.xsrfCookieName);

      if (xsrfValue) {
        requestHeaders.set(config.xsrfHeaderName, xsrfValue);
      }
    }

    // Remove Content-Type if data is undefined
    requestData === undefined && requestHeaders.setContentType(null);

    // Add headers to the request
    if ('setRequestHeader' in request) {
      utils.forEach(requestHeaders.toJSON(), function setRequestHeader(val, key) {
        request.setRequestHeader(key, val);
      });
    }

    // Add withCredentials to request if needed
    if (!utils.isUndefined(config.withCredentials)) {
      request.withCredentials = !!config.withCredentials;
    }

    // Add responseType to request if needed
    if (responseType && responseType !== 'json') {
      request.responseType = config.responseType;
    }

    // Handle progress if needed
    if (typeof config.onDownloadProgress === 'function') {
      request.addEventListener('progress', progressEventReducer(config.onDownloadProgress, true));
    }

    // Not all browsers support upload events
    if (typeof config.onUploadProgress === 'function' && request.upload) {
      request.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressEventReducer(config.onUploadProgress));
    }

    if (config.cancelToken || config.signal) {
      // Handle cancellation
      // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
      onCanceled = cancel => {
        if (!request) {
          return;
        }
        reject(!cancel || cancel.type ? new CanceledError(null, config, request) : cancel);
        request.abort();
        request = null;
      };

      config.cancelToken && config.cancelToken.subscribe(onCanceled);
      if (config.signal) {
        config.signal.aborted ? onCanceled() : config.signal.addEventListener('abort', onCanceled);
      }
    }

    const protocol = parseProtocol(fullPath);

    if (protocol && platform.protocols.indexOf(protocol) === -1) {
      reject(new AxiosError('Unsupported protocol ' + protocol + ':', AxiosError.ERR_BAD_REQUEST, config));
      return;
    }


    // Send the request
    request.send(requestData || null);
  });
}
```

**Code in */api/companion**

Companion:

```
import { auth, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { checkSubscription } from "@/lib/subscription";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const user = await currentUser();
    const { src, name, description, instructions, seed, categoryId } = body;

    if (!user || !user.id || !user.firstName) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!src || !name || !description || !instructions || !seed || !categoryId) {
      return new NextResponse("Missing required fields", { status: 400 });
    };

    const isPro = await checkSubscription();

    if (!isPro) {
      return new NextResponse("Pro subscription required", { status: 403 });
    }

    const companion = await prismadb.companion.create({
      data: {
        categoryId,
        userId: user.id,
        userName: user.firstName,
        description,
        instructions,
        name,
        seed,
        src,
      }
    });

    return NextResponse.json(companion);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[COMPANION_POST]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

CompanionID:

```
import { auth, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { checkSubscription } from "@/lib/subscription";

export async function PATCH(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { companionId: string } }
) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const user = await currentUser();
    const { src, name, description, instructions, seed, categoryId } = body;

    if (!params.companionId) {
      return new NextResponse("Companion ID required", { status: 400 });
    }

    if (!user || !user.id || !user.firstName) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!src || !name || !description || !instructions || !seed || !categoryId) {
      return new NextResponse("Missing required fields", { status: 400 });
    };

    const isPro = await checkSubscription();

    if (!isPro) {
      return new NextResponse("Pro subscription required", { status: 403 });
    }

    const companion = await prismadb.companion.update({
      where: {
        id: params.companionId,
        userId: user.id,
      },
      data: {
        categoryId,
        userId: user.id,
        userName: user.firstName,
        src,
        name,
        description,
        instructions,
        seed,
      }
    });

    return NextResponse.json(companion);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[COMPANION_PATCH]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
  }
};

export async function DELETE(
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: { companionId: string } }
) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    const companion = await prismadb.companion.delete({
      where: {
        userId,
        id: params.companionId
      }
    });

    return NextResponse.json(companion);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[COMPANION_DELETE]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

How would I fix this so email sign-ups get authorized when creating companion?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue all you have to do is go in clerk and active "username" in the sign in settings!